# How can I learn to manage multitasking when fighting in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've never understood how to use hotkeys (for eg: 4-barracks, 5-starport etc up to 8). How do the professionals (or even good amateurs) manage using keyboard left hand and mouse right hand? I am not a great typist but an average typer.

*What I am trying to say is:*  I am really unable to manage multi-tasking unless I use both hands on the keyboard. But while fighting, I cannot use 2 hands on keyboard, since mouse definitely needed on other hand. I am having problem especially while fighting even though I use all hotkeys (Grid hotkeys I mean )

Sorry if this question already asked, but before I ask already searched and I found some answers too like saying that we should use hotkeys etc..

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are having. Millions of players do not have problems with control scheme. If you are just playing worse that you would like and think that it's the fault of hotkeys - practice more, and do watch Day[9]'s [episode on hotkeys](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUohpQKVf_A) again. If you have some specific problem that you think other players don't have, please describe it in more detail.

Comment: @OrcJMR In above video link at 56:38 , he talks about Tapping. How does he moving and simuktaneously clickcing (4, q followed by 5,q  followed 6,q) I mean how does he able to do fast which I dont understand? Please explain on this

Comment: He does not press Q each time, the idea of tapping is just to select a building and check on its progress. Quick 456,456,456 is easy, and you only move a finger to Q every 10-15 seconds. Once again, do not try to catch up to Day[9] in speed - he's a pro-level player, even if he's not performing for several years.

Comment: You're supposed to use your left hand not only to use your hotkeys (eg 4-barracks) but also to train units, so you should always have one hand on the keyboard and one on the mouse. Force yourself to use hotkeys to produce units. (eg. S for SCVs, A for Marines...) It can be intimidating at first, but with practice it will become only natural and you'll increase greatly your APMs and thus your multitasking!

Comment: "S for SCVs, A for Marines" is the classic hotkey layout. It is easier for people familiar with SC1, but grid layout is in no way inferior, if you are using it - just to reassure :-)

Comment: Wait, there are hot keys? I just use my mouse alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most important thing in the match of Starcraft 2 is **making right decisions**.

For that, you need game experience to judge situations, and scouting to see those situations. You definitely don't need super-efficient hotkeys and godly micro. I've seen players who don't bind army units at all, only Nexus and production buildings, playing comfortably in Diamond league.

Don't try to fix everything in your game. Focus on macro, watch you replays and play more.

Comment: +1 True - Knowing how to do each action efficiently is one thing, but doing things in the most efficient order/manner is another. (Look at the big picture)

Comment: @aytimothy In this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUohpQKVf_A,     at 56:38 , he talks about Tapping. How does he moving and simuktaneously clickcing (4, q followed by 5,q followed 6,q) I mean how does he able to do fast which I dont understand? Please explain on this

Comment: @JohnG please do not copy comments. You can @-mention several people in one comment if you absolutely need to notify each of them. See above.

Comment: @OrcJMR - I thought you could only @-mention one person per comment?

Comment: @aytimothy Errr, you are right, I was somehow falsely convinced several mentions work. Still, as this is my answer, I've received a notification in that role implicitly.